# Add Buttons to TAB Bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an iphone app with tab bar controller and nav controller,when going to one page i need to change tab bar contents and add two buttons.

Is it possible?Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Companion

Answer (score 1):

check out "Managing Tabs at Runtime" in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW1